# Return previous row value in rdlc martrix

Tags: rdlc

Good day, I'm working with matrix for rdlc report. I'm trying to use "previous" function of rdlc in the matrix but it is not working because it is not supported by matrix tool. Does anyone know how can I achieve this result from matrix?

```
=IIF(Fields!CheckinCount.Value > 0,Fields!CheckinCount.Value,previous(Fields!CheckinCount.Value))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears it's not possible.
**"Not supported in chart or matrix data regions."**

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251678(v=vs.90).aspx